# Error Connecting BlueMix using Basic Connector

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-integration

I am facing the following error, when I run the ./startmgmt.sh, from the nativeapiadmin directory. I have already uploaded the public key file onto the connector, but strangely, I don't see any OK/Confirm button. So unable to understand if that has been correctly uploaded onto the server.

Request your help to resolve the issue 
PS: I have tried with both nativeapiadmin and root users. The results are the same

[image: Error - While starting the connector]

[image: Window to upload the Public Key - I don't see an OK/Submit button here]

Answer (score 0):

I tried following the installation steps on my machine and I was able to get it to work. Here are the details:

During the installation process, I noticed that the script started a Linux service, it did not just run  `startmgmt.sh`. The service file it started was in the dir of nativeapiadmin, and it was called `nativeapimgmt.service`. However, during the installation process, the script also created a link to this service file, so that it could be accessed like a normal service.

My system is running RHEL 7.2, so it uses [systemctl](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Services.html) to manage services. Therefore, in order to start the service, I ran `$ systemctl start nativeapimgmt` as root. And `$ systemctl stop nativeapimgmt` to stop it. I was able to see the connection status change in the Cloud Integration dashboard on Bluemix right away.

Depending on the flavor of Linux you are running, you may have a different service manager. e.g. on Ubuntu you would use:

```
$ service nativeapimgmt stop
$ service nativeapimgmt start
```

Re: the `id_rsa.pub file`, if you see the green check-mark beside the filename in Cloud Integration dashboard, it means it was successfully uploaded.

Comment: Running the $ service nativeapimgmt start is giving me an error: nativeapimgmt: unrecognized service. I am using Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer, Release:        6.6

Comment: Services were changed in RHEL 7. I think previous versions used [chkconfig](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-services-chkconfig.html). Try running `$ /sbin/chkconfig ––list` to get a list of services. If you see nativeapimgmt, then run `$ /sbin/service nativeapimgmt start` to start the service.

Comment: I took a look at the install script. For RHEL 6, it copies the configuration file to `/etc/init` and is starting it by running `$ start nativeapimgmt`. It also first checks if you have `start` in your path by running `$ which start`.